# addAPI(Games.API) app crashed

Tags: android, google-api, google-api-client, leaderboard

Hello I have a BIG problem with LeaderBoard

I Use thise code for login into gmail via app..

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

thise code run perfect. logIN into account and everything Okay..

But when I try open LeaderBoard with thise code..

```
Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient,  "XXXXX02386600-n1nl2jfkpgsuhi1bogkqhmitsadi4icl.apps.googleusercontent.com", 1337);

startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
                "XXXXXX02386600-n1nl2jfkpgsuhi1bogkqhmitsadi4icl.apps.googleusercontent.com"), 101);
```

and Write error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not configured to use the Games Api. Pass Games.API into GoogleApiClient.Biulder#addApi() tp use this feature
```

and If put .addApi(Games.API) into

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .addApi(Games.API)            
        .build();
```

application crashed.

I have thise imports

```
    import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.OptionalPendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
```

I don't have idea where is a problem, maybe wrong ID?  where I find good ID?

please if you have idea, or good code, please put here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

into google games not log in via google+ 
you need use BacisSamples from google developers. and inplements it into your code.